# Database Shrinking as a logged operation

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know if shrinking a data file is a logged operation or not. I do not have a definite answer to this. I have heard people say it is a logged operation but so far I did not see an evidence of this.

Comment: I can tell you this, if I have a DB setup with Log Shipping in full recovery mode and then shrink a data file and do nothing more, that same shrink operation is applied to the secondary DB so since it's only updating via Log Shipped transactions, it is therefore a logged transaction. I'm not 100% certain if recovery model makes any difference with this or not as well as any parameters you throw to it such as NOTRUNCATE but I wanted to share that little thought on the topic; I couldn't find anything definitive either online so I'll leave an answer to someone that can give reference as well.

Comment: There's an easy way to test it yourself: shrink a database and see if the space used in the transaction log file grows.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know if shrinking a data file is a logged operation or not.

It is fully logged operation and is severely bad process so **ALWAYS try to avoid it**. What it does is, when you hit the shrink button, quoting from [Paul Randal blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/)

> A data file shrink operation works on a single file at a time, and
>   uses the GAM bitmaps (see Inside The Storage Engine: GAM, SGAM, PFS
>   and other allocation maps) to find the highest page allocated in the
>   file. It then moves it as far towards the front of the file as it can,
>   and so on, and so on. In the case above, it completely reversed the
>   order of the clustered index, taking it from perfectly defragmented to
>   perfectly fragmented.

So basically it does page movement and frees empty space from the pages. This movement of page is logged in transaction log file. Due to this movement the logical ordering of pages changes and hence logical fragmentation comes in. The point to note here is this is not an atomic operation. If you stop the shrinking operation in between the changes done so far is not lost it is maintained and when you start next time it will continue from where it left.

See this Blog from Paul Randal for [data file size management](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/importance-of-data-file-size-management/) if you are worried about growing data file size.